# Drawing two 3D strings on Canvas?

Tags: android, matrix, camera, android-canvas

I have to draw 2 Strings on canvas.Strings must be drawn with the **same coordinates** and second string must be result of rotating first string 45 degrees around axis Y.The result must looks like  this:

[image]

This is my code:

```
Matrix matrix = new Matrix();
matrix = canvas.getMatrix();
mCamera = new Camera();


canvas.drawText("In the name of God", 30, 100, redPaint);
mCamera.rotateY(45);
mCamera.getMatrix(matrix);

matrix.preTranslate(30, 100);
//      matrix.postTranslate(-30, -100);

canvas.setMatrix(matrix);
canvas.drawText("In the name of God", 0, 0, greenPaint);
```

But result of above code is:

[image]

You can see that **coordinates of strings are different**.So what did I do wrong?I guess that it is be caused by incorrect arguments for `matrix.preTranslate()`.

**Update**:

I change my code like:

```
canvas.drawText("In the name of God", 30, 100, redPaint);
mCamera.rotateY(45);
mCamera.getMatrix(matrix);
matrix.preTranslate(-30, -100);
matrix.postTranslate(30, 100);
canvas.setMatrix(matrix);
canvas.drawText("In the name of God", 0, 0, greenPaint);
```

or like:

```
canvas.drawText("In the name of God", 30, 100, redPaint);
mCamera.rotateY(45);
mCamera.getMatrix(matrix);
matrix.preTranslate(-30, -100);
//matrix.postTranslate(30, 100);
canvas.setMatrix(matrix);
canvas.drawText("In the name of God", 0, 0, greenPaint);
```

or like:

```
canvas.drawText("In the name of God", 30, 100, redPaint);
mCamera.rotateY(45);
mCamera.getMatrix(matrix);

matrix.preTranslate(-30, -100);
//      matrix.postTranslate(30, 100);
canvas.setMatrix(matrix);
canvas.drawText("In the name of God", 30, 100, greenPaint);
```

And for all three above codes, result looks like this:

[image]

I guess that second text is drawn out of range or behind the `status bar` and so it is not visible.

Then change my code to:

```
mCamera.rotateY(45);
mCamera.getMatrix(matrix);
matrix.preTranslate(-30, -100);
matrix.postTranslate(30, 100);
canvas.setMatrix(matrix);
canvas.drawText("In the name of God", 30, 100, greenPaint);
```

result:

[image]

Comment: This question is related to http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6604504/how-to-rotate-a-canvas-at-a-specific-point-using-android-graphics-camera-rotatex

Comment: @eh9 I saw above question(How to rotate a canvas at a specific point ...),but I don't understand why he used `canvas.translate`.As you told before,I think that when we use Matrix.preTranslate(),we change the pivot of rotation to new origin.So why he used `canvas.translate`?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Thanks for replies.I solved the problem.I have to use `canvas.concat()` instead of `canvas.setMatrix`.This is correct code:

```
Matrix matrix = new Matrix();
mCamera = new Camera();

canvas.drawText("In the name of God", 30, 100, redPaint);
mCamera.rotateY(60);
mCamera.getMatrix(matrix);

matrix.preTranslate(-30, -100);
matrix.postTranslate(30, 100);
canvas.concat(matrix);
canvas.drawText("In the name of God", 30, 100, greenPaint);
```

Comment: Congratulations on finding that. That has got to be in the bottom 1% of worst-named API choices.

Comment: @eh9 I have a new problem,do you any idea about that?I tried to solve it my self,but I could not.I wrote it in this question :http://stackoverflow.com/questions/13548192/drawing-two-orthogonal-strings-in-3d-space-in-android-canvas

Answer (score 2):

Try this out:

```
Matrix matrix = new Matrix();
matrix = canvas.getMatrix();
mCamera = new Camera();


canvas.drawText("In the name of God", 30, 100, redPaint);
mCamera.translate(30, 100);
mCamera.rotateY(45);
mCamera.getMatrix(matrix);

canvas.setMatrix(matrix);
canvas.drawText("In the name of God", 0, 0, greenPaint);
```

I never mess with pre and post translate, but you can probably debug it and try doing a posttranslate instead of a pretranslate and supply (30, 100) and see if that works.

Comment: I try your code but only first drawn text(with red paint) is visible.

Comment: Also I change `mCamera.translate(30, 100);`  to `mCamera.translate(30, 100,0);`

Comment: Can you try doing the code, but not drawing the red text and see if the green text displays correctly?

Comment: I tried code without drawing red text,and there is no green text in result.I guess that second text is drawn out of range or behind the status bar and so it is not visible.

Comment: You mention the status bar. Perhaps you are not accounting for the status bar. Canvas does not know anything about the status bar, so when you put in raw X and Y coordinates, it will do coordinates with the status bar (that's the real X and Y coordinates). Could you try offsetting the Y values by the height of your status bar, for example doing a preTranslate(-30, -(100 + STATUS_BAR_HEIGHT)); and then doing a postTranslate(30, 100 + STATUS_BAR_HEIGHT);

Comment: If that doesn't do any changes, try just doing the postTranslate(30, 100 + STATUS_BAR_HEIGHT) and see if that yields what you want.

Comment: My purpose is drawing 2 Strings with the same coordinates.All time the red text is visible and when we draw red text,we ignore the status bar and it's height.If green text was drawn in correct coordinates,it must that some green characters be visible,but no green characters are visible.Also when we increase the height of red text,green text has not hide by status bar.

Answer (score 1):

The rotation described by the matrix object always has the property that its axis of rotation pass through the origin. Every point in the axis of rotation is invariant under the rotation, which is a fancy (and compact) way of saying that it doesn't change. The way you've described your desired outcome, you want left edge of the text not to move. That means the left edge of the text has to be on that invariant axis.

This is what `pretranslate()` is for. You want a translation that takes the position of the text to the origin. The coordinates of that translation are the negative of the coordinates:

```
matrix.preTranslate(-30, -100);
```

This translation is applied to the text, not to the axis of rotation. That confusion seems to have been the source of your problem. To put the text back where it was before, use `postTranslate` with the negative of the pre-translation, that is, with the original coordinates.

To understand this better overall, read up on [similarity transforms](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Matrix_similarity).

Comment: I change `matrix.preTranslate(30, 100);` to `matrix.preTranslate(-30, -100);matrix.postTranslate(30, 100);` and try both `canvas.drawText("...", 0, 0, greenPaint);` and `canvas.drawText("...", 30, 100, greenPaint);` but no one is correct.

Comment: What do the results look like? Please edit your question. It's entirely possible I've misread the Android documentation; such things have a horrible habit of being sloppy about coordinate systems.

Comment: Please see my question again,I add some snippet codes and their  results.